# Verifiable Delay Function - Fake Proofs

Tags: rsa, group-theory

For unknown group order such as RSA groups $ G %$, it takes $T$ sequential steps to compute the below function (time-lock puzzle).

$$ y = g^{2^T} mod N$$

[This](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/623.pdf) paper states that if $ /Phi(N) $ (Group order) is known, it takes only two exponentiation to compute $y$.

$$ e = 2^T mod |G| $$
$$ y = g^e $$

I am not sure I understand how these two results are equivalent.

Comment: $e = 2^T mod |N|$ should be $e = 2^T \bmod \varphi (N)$. Knowing the $\varphi$ helps to reduce the power. The  two exponentiation are the last two exponentiation. The operations re not counted.

Comment: I know it is reduced. However,  I give values to check the results but it fails

Comment: Did you compute $y = g^e \bmod N$? This is also needed.